# How to upload a file in a urllib2 request

Tags: python, request, urllib2, kairos-api

I'm trying to use the kairos facial recognition API, and I need to upload a local file. The api documentation says that the image parameter needs to be a "Publicly accessible URL or Base64 encoded photo." In the [example code](https://pastebin.com/C1LM9WeK), they use the `data` parameter for `urllib2.request`, and to this they pass the `values` string which I think is json. My question is, how can I give them a local file instead of the url `"http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg"`?

Comment: It would be easier for us to answer if we could see your code. I'm also not clear as to what you're asking. I get the overall question but have you tried passing a local file path? Also are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3+? It also somewhat depends on your file system and wether or not you want it to be cross platform. Something like                                                     r = urllib2.urlopen('file://' + some_path) should work. I may be able to help you more if you can answer my few questions and post and update of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the local image and do a base64 encoding. You can then pass it as "image" key-value pair in "values" that you form.

Below is a sample code. It does not use urllib2. But its not too different.

```
with open ('messi.jpg','rb') as imgFh:
    img = imgFh.read()

values = {"image": b64encode(img),
    "subject_id": "Messig",
    "gallery_name": "faces"}
```

You can pass this "values" as "data" in you request. It should work.